# CSS overlay div with another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Goal:** I am trying to move divs ( blue + green ) above banner ( red ).

Purple div have different amount of content, so its height is variable. 
Consider header (yellow) and banner ( red ) with fixed height so you can use fixed position.

My try is in jsfiddle.

**JsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/dEb3m/

[image: goal]

This is final output.

[image: new]

Banner is in background. News (green) is relative to main ( orange )

**HTML:**

```
<div id="header">header</div>
<div id="banner">banner</div>

<div id="search">search</div>

<div id="news">

    <div class="new_item">new 1</div>
    <div class="new_item">new 2</div>
    <div class="new_item">new 3</div>

</div>

<div style="clear: both;"></div>

<div id="main">main</div>
<div id="footer">footer</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#header, #banner, #main, #footer {
    width: 400px;
}

#banner {
    height: 100px;
}

#search {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
}

#news {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
}

.new_item {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    min-height: 100px;
    width: 150px;
    max-width: 150px;
}
```

Comment: The image just looks like a mess to me. I would normally have a go but I cant even tell what you want overall. Random `overflow` why not just get rid of the 3rd item if you don't want it? Or you want it pushed under? So unclear. Maybe its just me but this looks like hell.

Comment: Goal: I am trying to move 2 divs (blue + green) above banner (red).

Comment: You mean like banner in the background? Why don't make the banner the first container? That's not what your image show

Comment: So give `#banner` a `position:absolute;` and a `z-index:-1;`

Comment: Why not use `position: relative` or `position: absolute`?

Comment: @Danko Yes, make banner as background.

Comment: You mean like this http://jsfiddle.net/dEb3m/10/ ?

Comment: Why not just start over and make a layout that works. That's a much better idea. If you have to come here to ask how to make it you will have no luck when trying to place content. Things will move or not be the correct height etc and you will just come back with them problems.

Comment: The common situation when it's easier to find a solution for your problem than to fix a wrong solution proposed.

Comment: @Danko somethink like that, BUT I showed you just simplest example. Banner is `<div id="banner"><img...></div>` so don't assume that background of banner is red.

Comment: The banner bg could also be an image .... or like other comment say use of `relative and absolute` positions

Comment: @Danko like this ... [http://jsfiddle.net/dEb3m/11/](http://jsfiddle.net/dEb3m/11/)

Comment: So you have that example the question is already solved?

Comment: I'm still unsure what you want, but this fiddle at least gets three divs above the banner. http://jsfiddle.net/dEb3m/16/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dEb3m/11/)

CSS:

```
#header, #banner, #main, #footer {width: 400px;}
#header {background-color: yellow;}
#banner {background-color: red;height: 50px;position:absolute;z-index:-1;}
#search {background-color: blue;width: 100px;float: left;margin-top:20px;}
#news {background-color: green;display: inline-block;width: 300px;overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap;margin-top:20px;}
.new_item {
    vertical-align:top;
    white-space: normal;
    background-color: pink;
    display: inline-block;
    min-height: 100px;
    width: 150px;
    max-width: 150px;
}
#main {background-color: orange;}
#footer {background-color: silver;}
```

Answer (score 0):

When do you to move the divs ( blue + green ) above banner ( red )?

**If it is always**, you can use the following CSS code:

```
#banner {
    margin-bottom: -50px;
}
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tzi/8CWBa/) to play with.

**If it is just when you scroll**, you can use the following CSS code:

```
#banner {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
}
#search,
#news {
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tzi/Ef5Ay/) to play with.

Cheers,
Thomas.